# Spawn Python script on remote box using ssh from within python

Tags: python, bash, ssh

i am currently writing a script which is supposed to manage multiple servers. Basically I have a python script on my own machine which i will refer to as **Host** as well as multiple servers. When running my Host-Python script, I need to find a way to connect to my server via ssh and spawn a second python script on the server. The issue here is that.

A) The script on the server can technically run indefinetely 
 B) My
local script is supposed to be stopped or issue other commands after
he ssh command has been issued.

This means that my python script needs to:

1. log into the remote box
2. start a python script in the background
3. exit the box again

The result should be that there is only the python script running in the background of my server.

I tried multiple ways now and none seems to really work out. Every single solution i tried so far results in my local script being blocked.

My current script looks like this:

```py
def call_command(target, command):
    command = f'ssh -o ProxyJump={CONFIG["proxy"]}:{CONFIG["port"]} {target} "{command}"'
    try:
        subprocess.call(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to execute command on {target}: {e.output}")

call_command("server_1", "cd ~/Script/ && nohup python3 Client.py > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown")
```

As stated before, this seems to block and my program is halted when calling the given command. I have looked into the box while my local script was running and found this:

```bash
> ps aux | grep python3
bash -c cd ~/Script/ &&nohup python3 Client.py > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

So for some reason this call seems to be running while the underlying called script is running. Do you have any solution for this?

I am happy for any help!

Comment: `shell=True` is an _extremely_ bad idea. If someone tells you their proxy server is `$(rm -rf ~)`, you don't want your host to run that command. Specify your command as a list, not a string, and keep the `shell` argument at its default `False`.

Comment: Also, note that `disown` (1) is a bashism, so it isn't guaranteed to work with `/bin/sh`; and (2) isn't necessary with noninteractive shells anyhow, since they don't have job control enabled and don't forward HUP signals in the first place. And you certainly never need to use _both_ `nohup` and `disown`. Add `</dev/null` and you need _neither_.

Comment: Regarding the shell=True, I agree with you. 
Regarding the disown; could that already be the issue? i have tried without the disown and that didnt work either.

Comment: The disown will cause your command to have a nonzero exit status, but that has nothing to do with whether the script is successfully started.

Comment: What I'd suggest you do first is change `>/dev/null` to `/tmp/some.log` and _read that log_.

Comment: Okay give me 3 minutes

Comment: [BashFAQ/063](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/063) might be relevant here.

Comment: `['ssh', '-o', f'ProxyJump={CONFIG["proxy"]}:{CONFIG["port"]}', target, command]` 
and `shell=False` also eliminates the potential for quoting-related bugs altogether, to let you run commands where the quotes added by the outer f-string could muck up their execution. Your _current_ command doesn't appear to be one of those, but it's still a common problem.

Comment: so I did feed it into `log.txt` and the output is as expected. thats the normal output of the program.

Comment: It creates log.txt on the remote server? So your program is successfully being started on the remote server? Great to hear!

Comment: Which is to say, if your real problem is "my program doesn't run only when its stdout and stderr are directed to `/dev/null`", that's a different problem with a different answer, and folks investigating it can look in different places.

Comment: yes. Sorry if that wasnt clear. when calling `ps aux` and grep for python3, I can see the python3 process itself and the nohup version.

Comment: it was always running. the problem is not that its not running. the problem is that my ssh session on my local end is being blocked

Comment: Ahh. Have you followed the advice to add `</dev/null` (in my 2nd comment) yet?

Comment: (By the way, I would never write code like this myself personally, at least, not if you know the remote box is running a reasonably modern Linux distro where you can use `systemd-run` to set up a background process under systemd's supervision; that way logs are retained in the journal, there's a record of exit status, &c., but the process is _very_ thoroughly detached unless you go out of your way to make it otherwise).

Comment: mhm I think that may be a little over the top here. Its more a small utility to monitor a few things. I tried adding `</dev/null` and i am simply seeing the output of the program directly in my shell now

Comment: Did you maybe _replace_ the original `>/dev/null 2>&1`? You still need them; `</dev/null` is an addition, not a replacement.

Comment: Yes I did. were I not supposed to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252908/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-finn-eggers).

Comment: This is outside the scope of the question as asked, but why reinvent the wheel when Ansible and other tools are more than equipped to do this (and a ton of other tasks) in a more secure, configurable, and scalable way?

Comment: this is really just supposed to be a small helper within 100 lines of python code. I am not sure adding other projects to this reduces complexity

Answer (score 0):

C programmers will routinely put an immortal worker process
into the background by calling
[daemon()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon).

Python programmers can do
[the same](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon).
But you might not even need to import a library.

A simple paramiko invocation of

```
$ ssh server "daemonize python3 Client.py"
```

might suffice.

The
https://linux.die.net/man/1/daemonize
man page explains that it exactly fits OP's use case.
The key is to simplify the details so there's
no need to contact SO for assistance.
This is an ordinary situation with a well-documented solution.
Skip the fancy shell punctuation and
just use the packaged solution.

Comment: This is true, but it's utterly unnecessary in the OP's present circumstances.

Comment: We have solved the issue with wrapping the command into:

```
 exec python3 .... >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

@Charles Duffy managed to find the solution using:

```
exec python3 Client.py >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null
```

instead of

```
python3 Client.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```